# Unable to join Wifi Network

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a strange unexplainable issue with connecting to my home wifi. Let me set this up. I use a Macbook Pro 2016 and iPhone 6S. My router is in the same room that I use the said devices and had always been working fine. Until today.

This morning when I tried to use my MBP, I am unable to join the wifi network that I am usually always on. However, my iPhone is having none of the issues. My iPhone can still connect to the wifi. Strangely enough, I couldn't even connect my MBP to my iPhone's hotspot in the said room. So I did all the troubleshooting methods; delete the necessary network files in the SystemConfiguration folder, reset MBP, reset router, reset NVRAM, and Reset SMC. Still didn't solve the issue.

So I tried moving away from the router, outside my room. Then it worked. I was able to connect to my wifi. When I moved back into my room, the connection died and disconnected. So my question is, what the? There are no new wireless devices in my environment, so I don't understand why as I move away from the router I am able to connect to the network as opposed to moving closer to the router.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried running Apple Hardware test? It sounds like it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: @NoahL But I am still able to connect to the network, just not in the same room as the router. I'll give it a try anyway.

Comment: @NoahL I just tested joining a wifi in a cafe without issue.

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong in that room. I'd move the router out to another room to see if that fixes the issue.